# why does pollFirst/Last() fails to retrieve every element of a NavigableSet while iterating using the for statement?

Tags: java

while trying to retrieve elements from the set, i preferred using pollFirst() because it reduces clunky propositions and helps to remove elements after their retrieval. To iterate over the set, i used a general "for" approach which allowed only a part of the set to be retrieved. I did some search and was able to find a solution that suggested to use while statement. But WHY did it happen?
To ease out the problem statement i have provided subtle comments.

```
    class SetTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>();
        ts.add(new String(new String("one")));
        ts.add("two");
        ts.add(new String("three"));
        NavigableSet<String> ns = new TreeSet<String>();
        ns.addAll(ts);
        System.out.println("Before while " + ns.size());// gives us 3
        while (ns.size() != 0)
            ns.pollFirst();
        System.out.println("After while " + ns.size());// gives us 0.
        System.out.println("Before for " + ts.size());// gives us 3
        for (int i = 0; i < ts.size(); i++)
            ts.pollFirst();
        System.out.println("After for " + ts.size());// gives us 1. WHY??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because the size of `ts` changes during the for loop, for example if the size is equal to 10 the loop will probably go like this:

```
i = 0; size = 10
i = 1; size = 9
i = 2; size = 8
i = 3; size = 7
i = 4; size = 6
i = 5; size = 5 -> breaks the for loop.
```

EDIT:
Forgot to mention that you can fix it by changing the condition to

```
for(int i = 0; ts.size() != 0; i++)
```

Or by keeping the size in an external variable and using that in the for loop.